# How to check if my Google Drive embed videos using iframe ends?

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I have this react code that I want to trigger the `onEnded` attribute but it doesn't seem to be get triggered when my iframe player ends. Here's a sample for it. Btw, I am using the embed link of my Google Drive's videos.

```
            <iframe
              allowFullScreen
              src={videoDetail && videoDetail[0] ? videoDetail[0].videoUrl : ""}
              style={{ border: "none", width: "100%", height: "60vh" }}
              title={
                videoDetail && videoDetail[0]
                  ? videoDetail[0].title
                  : "Default Title"
              }
              onEnded={() => console.log("i want to run a function here.")}
            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there's no way you can use the `onEnded` function for Google Drive embed videos. I resorted to using `react-player` component and uploaded the videos to `Vimeo`.